# Linux nslookup reverse lookup returning error

Tags: linux, dns, ip-address

I am on a Linux machine and am trying to lookup the machine name of a remote Windows computer using it's IP address.

When I use `nslookup` to get the IP address from the machine name, it works:

```
$ nslookup computer-name
Server:         172.22.333.444
Address:        172.22.333.444#53

Name:   computer-name.example.com
Address: 172.55.6.77
```

However, when I try to lookup the machine name from the IP address, I get an error:

```
$ nslookup 172.55.6.77
Server:         172.22.333.444
Address:        172.22.333.444#53

** server can't find 77.6.55.172.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN
```

When I use `nmblookup` it works fine:

```
$ nmblookup -A 172.55.6.77
Looking up status of 172.55.6.77
        computer-name   <00> -         M <ACTIVE> 
        group           <00> - <GROUP> M <ACTIVE> 
        computer-name   <20> -         M <ACTIVE> 

        MAC Address = 11-22-33-BA-44-55
```

Any reason for why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reverse DNS configured for the network in question

Answer (score 0):

You are using different network services:

`nslookup` does a DNS lookup.

`nmblookup` does a NETBIOS lookup.

Their answers don't even have to match, since each service keeps an independent mapping of hosts.